# Laravel Mail via smtp Timeout Error

Tags: php, email, laravel, swiftmailer

I'm trying to figure out what is happening to an email sent via Laravel's `Mail::...` function. The email is not being sent, and I am receiving the following error message:

> exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Connection to mail_server:25 Timed Out' in /srv/www/application/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:405

And my `app/config/mail.php` settings:

```
return array(
  'driver' => 'smtp',
  'host' => 'mail_server',
  'port' => 25,
  'from' => array('address' => null, 'name' => null),
  //'encryption' => 'tls',
  'username' => null,
  'password' => null,
  'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
  'pretend' => false,
);
```

One issue is that this usually works fine, but once in a while, I get the above error, and it seems to only happens for specific domains. For example, sending mail to `bob@test.com` and `mike@other.com` works fine, but as soon as you try sending to `jack@specific.com` or `jill@specific.com` the timeout message logged and the mail does not sent.

Here's the function that sends the mail:

```
$message = "";
$result = Mail::send('templates.email', $form, function($mail) use (&$from_email, &$from_name, &$to_email, &$subject, &$message, &$emails){
  $mail->from($from_email, $from_name);
  $mail->to($to_email);
  if (count($emails)>0)
    $mail->cc($emails);
  $mail->subject($subject);
  $message = $mail->getSwiftMessage();
  $message->setCharset('iso-8859-1');
  $message->setMaxLineLength(1000);
  $message->setContentType('multipart/mixed');
});
```

I figured that this was an end-user issue, as it only seems to happen to a few specific domains, but the error message indicates that the connection to my `mail_server` is timing out before the mail can even be sent. If anyone else has encountered this issue, that would be great. All my attempts at finding a solution have provided answers that do not apply to Laravel or this specific problem.

**Edit**

Note, all mail sent from this Laravel Application is handled in a Queue, so overworking/concurrency shouldn't be the issue here.

Comment: Timeout errors connecting to mail servers are not uncommon.  Most mail servers (e.g. sendmail) start refusing connections once they are too busy, or even start refusing connections if they have received too many connections from the same host in a given time frame.  The simple answer is to put your mail messages into a database table, and use an artisan task to send them. If the sending fails then just try again later.

Comment: @delatbabel A valid point, which reminds me of something I forgot to add to the question. All mail sent from this laravel application are handled in a Queue; that is I don't think overworking the mail server is the issue in this case. I'll edit this information into the question, thanks.

Answer (score -2):

For Gmail,change the driver from smtp to sendmail. I have been scratching my head over this for almost an hour until I stumbled on that.